# Optimized rate of frequency of changing title and description/keywords meta-tag?

Tags: meta-tags

OK we can change the content at any frequency. But what about `<title>`, description-meta tag, keywords meta tag. I think if we change title, description, keywords of any website daily, then that may affect page ranking. What is the real fact? What is the minimum and maximum rate of frequency to change these items? Legal practice may different from successful practice. Please explain me.

NOTE: 
If this type of question answered before, then mention the link and please don't close or ban the question.

Comment: FYI, meta tags do not affect a page's rankings

Comment: Respected Sir, Sorry if my question is duplicate. But I could not understood the answer. Please give your valuable guidance. May I change my title, description and keyword of a particular page(or link) of my website daily. If yes then is that affect search result and page rank?? Please answer. Thank You.

Comment: What is duplicate and what is original? Whatever the answer but I could not get my answer in the name of duplicate question. Thank you all Original masters. It is just like slapping on Galilio's face by so called wise men after discovering the fact that Earth revolve round the Sun by Galilio. If my question disturb some body. Then please give me a link of another forum site where there were no point system.